# Read a line from the console

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I am reading several string such as name , surname , student number and grades, the first three  I have done as follows:

```
 cout<<"Enter the student's first name: "<<endl;
            string name;
            cin>>name;
            cout<<"Enter the student's last name: "<<endl;
            string surname;
            cin>>surname;
            cout<<"Enter the student's unique student number: "<<endl;
            string studentNo;
            cin>>studentNo;
```

How grades are enter in the following manner : " 90 78 65 33 22"  and I want read the entire line of grade into a string variable. All these  string are used to construct student object.

How would I achieve this, I tried using getline() but this does not work.

**My attempt:**

```
 int main(){

cout<<"Enter the student's first name: "<<endl;
                string name;
                cin>>name;
                cout<<"Enter the student's last name: "<<endl;
                string surname;
                cin>>surname;
                cout<<"Enter the student's unique student number: "<<endl;
                string studentNo;
                cin>>studentNo;
                string classRcd;
               std::getline(cin , classRcd);
               db.add_student( name , surname , studentNo , classRcd); 
    /*Creates a student object and add it to a list in db which is of type database*/
               clear();  //clears the screen in a while loop
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What behavior of `cin >> v` is it that you want?

Comment: Do you have a full example? As far as I know std::getline does wait for input.

Comment: The question is very unclear. Please describe what you want to achieve, what you have tried, and in which way it did not work as expected.

Comment: `getline(std::cin, studentNo)` should do the trick

Comment: @Matthew much better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have a new line in the stream after `cin>>studentNo`, which is giving you an empty string for the `classRcd`.

You could solve it by just adding another `getline()` call after `cin>>studentNo` and leaving alone the result, or ignore the new line by `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Answer (score 5):

```
std::string line;
std::getline( std::cin, line );
```

There is another `getline()` that is a member function of the stream; that one is usually not what you want.

Comment: Tried that, but It does not allow me to type input.

Comment: @Matthew: Then please post an example of the code that does not work, because you did something wrong. Posting the code that works and saying "the next step didn't work" is not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using getline(). It can be done in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  cout << "Enter grades : ";
  string grades;
  getline(cin, grades);
  cout << "Grades are : " << grades << endl;
  return 0;
}
```